# Redis get key or set to default if none exists

Tags: redis

Is there a command in redis where I can set a default value for a key if it does not exist?

For example if `get hello` returns `(nil)` I would like to default it to `world`. But if the key `hello` already exists, I would like to return this value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with a Lua script:

```
local value = redis.call("GET", KEYS[1])
if (not value) then
    redis.call("SET", KEYS[1], ARGV[1])
    return ARGV[1]
end
return value
```

Save this as `script.lua` and call it like this:

```
$ redis-cli eval "$(cat script.lua") 1 myKey defaultValue
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use SETNX to put the default value and then do a normal GET.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Get should be the fastest thing to do

```
// practically Get would suffer a miss only the first time
value = Get key
if value not nil
  return value

// Get did not find key => setNX
saved = SetNX key default
if saved 
  return default

// SetNX discovered key value was already set by someone else => Get it
return Get key
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible as you can see in the other answers, be aware that depending on your use case, it may be faster to make 2 requests instead. For 2 reasons. The first is that it forces you to "compute" the output which is what you are trying to avoid with a cache in the first place. And second you will send a script AND the computed data with each requests which slows down traffic, where if your data stays the same for a while, you will only send a simple `get` request.

This is why a get-or-set is better if implemented in your app or at the driver level. I don't know the language you use, but here is a pseudo code version:

```
function get_or_set(key, callback_function)
  value = REDIS.get(key)
  if value.nil?
    value = callback_function(REDIS) # pass REDIS to the anonymous function just in case
    value_str = pack(value) # could be JSON or MsgPack
    REDIS.set(key, value_str)
  else
    unpack(value)
  end
end
```

This simplified because it only takes care of string (packing to make sure they are strings) and no expire is implemented, but you get the idea.

While it sounds overkill, it is how you get better performance. Otherwise it definitely would be a Redis feature already.